# ruby how to stop the execution after rescue

Tags: ruby, raise, rescue

I have a func where when an exception was raised, I am rescuing it.
But the program continues to the next line and calls the next func `create_request`

But when there is exception, I do not want to continue

```
def  validate_request_code options    
  if check_everything is good
     #code to validate
  else
   errors << "something is gone bad"
  end
[errors.size == 0, errors.size == 0 ? options : raise(ArgumentError, "Error while validating #{errors}")]
end
```

I am trying to catch/rescue the exception

```
def validate_request options

  begin
   validate_request_code options
  rescue ArgumentError => e
      log :error
  rescue Exception => e
      log :error 
  end

  sleep 20
  
  if options['action'] == "create"
    create_request options
  end
end
```

Comment: Of course execution continues after you have handled the exception. That's the point of exception handling. It is not clear to me, what you want to achieve, but you can re-raise the exception from within the rescue block, or raise a new exception. Technically, you could even exit the program or commit suicide by [sending a termination signal](https://apidock.com/ruby/Process/kill/class) to yourself, but the cases where this is the desired action are extremely rare.

Comment: What is that `[400, ["..."]]` part – are you using a web framework? If so, it might have a built-in way to return early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by 'not continue' you mean that you want the original error to continue (i.e., you just want to take action on the way by), you can call `raise` inside the rescue block, which re-raises the original error.

```rb
def foo
  begin
    # stuff
  rescue StandardError => e
    # handle error
    raise  
  end
end
```

You can also simply return from within the `rescue` block as well.

```rb
def foo
  begin
    # stuff
  rescue StandardError => e
    # handle error
    return some_value  
  end
end
```

As an aside, generally you want to rescue `StandardError` rather than `Exception`. All the things that you can reasonably handle within your application are covered under the `StandardError`. The things outside that are things like out-of-memory, etc., that are outside your control.

Comment: When I return in the rescue block I'm getting deprecation warnings